# eBay REST API Get Offers Authetication Error

Tags: rest, api, ebay-api

I am attempting to get eBay product IDs using the GetOffers request by sending it a product SKU.

My code is below, the problem I am currently having is that when I try to test this code is returns a 401 unauthorized. It's not returning any specific error code or anything descriptive.

I know my access token is valid I can't find any good examples on how to use this request.

```
public string getEbayOffers(string sku)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        string accessToken = "tokenhere";
        string param = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(accessToken));
        string url = $"sell/inventory/v1/offer?sku={sku}";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.ebay.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", param);
            response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        }
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- No need to convert your token to base64. The correct format should be "Bearer **YOUR_USER_TOKEN**". Replace **YOUR_USER_TOKEN** with your own token string.
- **Access token** should be enough for getting offers but maybe you can try to use user token if above doesn't work.